# SQL: Trigger that references 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This is probably a silly question but its got me chasing my tail.

Order table and products table, if quantity ordered exceeds quantity in stock then...

I've probably googled 50 key words, check 3 books, can't find the way to do this.  This is the premise of what I've trying to do, not what I've tried.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_qty
ON order_details
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
IF (SELECT quantity FROM inserted) > products.quantity_in_stock
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Orderded quantity cannot exceed quantity in stock'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
```

Where can I join them?  I've tried 20 different ways, tried declaring a variable in front, I cannot find a way to do this.

Cheers.

Comment: MSDN has exactly what you need.  Take a look at example C: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Consider stored procedures as an easier alternative to triggers.  If you use a stored procedure to update order lines, it would be fairly easy to modify to check for sufficient stock first.

Comment: Think about the fact that you always can insert more than one record into a table at the same time, possibly even affecting different products. Your trigger approach does not reflect that possibility, but it must. Every trigger that involves `inserted` or `deleted` and *is not a set operation* is critically flawed. Before you design a trigger, you must define what should happen if someone inserts 20 records, of which some are okay, and some are not. (If you want to allow single-record inserts only, you could use a stored procedure.)

Comment: Thanks to all.

Maurice, I've been reading through that and mostly trial and erroring.  I'm missing the why to make myself understand it though.

Andomar & Tomalak, this is a school assignment for the purpose of learning how triggers work, not a real database.  I have to work within what I've been given.

Comment: That does not change a lot. ;) It's always sensible to assume that inserting multiple records is a possibility. Can you show the schema for the tables involved?

Comment: ERD: http://oi45.tinypic.com/29cb6sm.jpg

This is exactly what I've been asked to do.
**Create an INSERT and UPDATE trigger called tr_check_qty on the order_details table to only allow orders of products that have a quantity in stock greater than or equal to the units ordered.  Run the following query to verify your trigger.**

Comment: I see. The question is a bit ambiguous. I assume the teacher wanted to keep it simple, but in real life you're going to trip over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_qty ON order_details
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  -- rollback transaction if any product type in order exceeds stock amount
  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      inserted
      INNER JOIN products ON inserted.product_id = products.product_id
    GROUP BY
      products.product_id
    HAVING
      SUM(inserted.quantity) > MAX(products.quantity_in_stock)
  )
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Ordered quantity cannot exceed quantity in stock'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  END
END
```

It works for both single-row inserts and multi-row inserts.

Comment: You need to use MIN(), MAX(), or AVG() for products.quantity_in_Stock otherwise you'll count the quantity_in_stock multiple times.